# Who are the Gomerites?

Tags: gentiles, parashat-noach

So I am reading Parashas Noach,and it lists Gomer, grandson of Yefes there.And obviously all the descendants became nations. But, who, according to the chachamim are the Gomerites today?
Thanks

Comment: I don't have the source in front of me, but there is a Midrash somewhere in Bereishis Rabbah that says that 16 families of Bnei Noach were wiped out at some point, replaced by 16 families of Bnei Avraham. So perhaps the Gomerites aren't around today, nor were they around for very long.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the Gomerites? There are seventy options; why did you pick him to ask on? (Feel free to follow my example and ask seventy questions; we probably wouldn't be able to answer the large majority of them, though.)

Comment: Didn't they end up in Mayberry, North Carolina? <grin>

Comment: `And obviously all the descendants became nations.` Why is this obvious? `But, who, according to the chachamim are the Gomerites today` Why assume that they are even extant today, as a distinct group, or otherwise?

Comment: @DonielF I would be interested in seeing that Midrash, if you have a chance to find it.

Comment: @chaim I'll have to dig it up, but it's in the context of the flood in the times of Enosh.

Answer (score 4):

The the gomerites according to [Radak commenting on ובני גומר אשכנז](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40230&st=&pgnum=56)  and Rabeinu Saadiah Gaon on וריפת were identified with people living in Germany and the Gauls in France. See [peirsuh of R. Dovid Zvi Hoffman](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/hofman/hof_br10.pdf) for other identifications.